# Broadcast message between two different users

Tags: c#, inno-setup, broadcast, sendmessage

I'm trying to send a custom message from an elevated setup (on a Windows Seven) to a running application written in C#.
Unfortunately this message is never received in C# app.
Is this because setup and app are running under different user?
How can I solve this?

To make it easy:

```
// --- C# code ---

    private const int WM_CUSTOM_CLOSE = 0x400 + 0x500;
    private const int CUSTOM_CLOSE_WPARAM = 0x1;
    private const int CUSTOM_CLOSE_LPARAM = 0x2;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_CUSTOM_CLOSE)
        {
            int wp = m.WParam.ToInt32();
            int lp = m.LParam.ToInt32();
            if (wp == CUSTOM_CLOSE_WPARAM && lp == CUSTOM_CLOSE_LPARAM)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Close application");
                Close();
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

// --- INNO SETUP code ---

    const 
      WM_USER = $400;
      WM_CUSTOM_CLOSE = WM_USER + $500;
      WM_CUSTOM_WPARAM = $1;
      WM_CUSTOM_LPARAM = $2;
    function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
    begin
      SendNotifyMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_CUSTOM_CLOSE, 
                        WM_CUSTOM_WPARAM, WM_CUSTOM_LPARAM);
    end;
```

Comment: i've had a similar problem... my workaround was this: i already had an named pipe open for inter-programm communication, and added a control message there to close down my app ... from inno-setup i call my installed prog exe with a param that will not start up the whole app, but connect to the named pipe and tell the other instance to exit ...

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42: can you post an example? Named pipes under Inno Setup are a nightmare for me. Thanks

Comment: I've also thought to use a manual reset event created in my app and set in setup, but I don't know how to use OpenEvent in InnoSetup...

Comment: I'd try sending a registered message (RegisterWindowMessage on both sides).

Comment: don't try named pipes inside inno-setup ... in your running app, you listen on the named pipe ... and in the very same app, implement a startup parameter that will bypass normal application startup, and instead connect to the running instance that is listening, and transfer an exit message ... from inno setup, all you have to do is start a new instance of your running app but with a parameter

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42: sounds cool, I'll try as soon as I can. Thanks.

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42: if you post this as possible solution I will accept it. I've used a similar method: in C# app I created a manual reset event and a thread waiting for it to be set (and close app when true), while when app is run with a special param, that event is set. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no real "solution" but a workaround...

implement the handling for a special startup parameter in the running prog

if started with that param, the program should skip all normal startup and connect to a waiting named-pipe / manual reset event in the running instance, and message that instance to shutdown

from your setup, all you need to do is start the program with that special param